# Explanation of an notation List<name.test> nameList

Tags: apex, list, sobject, code

I have a piece of code as following:

```
List<name.test> nameList
```

In List  is name a class or object. Why would we use such an annotation?

Or for example:

```
method(name.test variable)
```

Comment: Using upper case first letters on class names and lower case first letters on variable names (or vice versa) can help a bit `List<Name.Test> nameList`. So can better class names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably because the clas `Name` contains the definition of another inner class like this:

```
public class name{
   public class test{
   }
}
```

If so, you have to specify the parent class name before referencing the `test` inner class.

So if you want to make a list of records of type `name.test`, you have to use: `List<name.test>`